# questions about windows licencing

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, licensing

I'd like to switch to Linux (Ubuntu) as my primary OS, but I'd like to keep Windows as virtual machine for some tasks. Curently I have activated Windows on bare metal.

I know that I need new licence for that virtual machine, but there is some 'magic' when lincence is linked to my account, that i do not fully understand. And I have two questions about it:

**1) when I reinstall my linux and I'll keep my virtual HDD** - can I continue to use my previously activated windows on newly installed Ubuntu on same metal?

**2) when I reinstall my linux and I'll lose my virtual HDD** - can new windows installation in virtual enviroment recognize my computer and use my previous 'virtual machine' licence as normal installation do?

Thank you!

---

PS: I tried to talk to microsoft, but after two hours of trying to contact them by phone I just gave up....

Comment: You can resize your partitions so you could keep your Windows license. No the license will not persist, you can check under your laptop or computer case if the license key is there.

Comment: Can you please specify your Windows version?

Comment: @sudo I really want to use it in virtual machine

Comment: @CaldeiraG windows 10, latest that I can download from MS

Comment: @LuciusNagata you can extract your Windows license if that's what your aiming for.